# How can I proof that a system of nonlinear equations is concave or convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-system

I have a system of nonlinear equations and what define if it is concave or convex. probably it is solved by using Hessian matrix, but I don't know how to do this. Someone can help me?